# jQuery Masonry fit inside container when bricks have margins

Tags: jquery, html, css, jquery-masonry

I have a 960 pixel wide `#container` that I have 4 240px bricks that are powered by jQuery masonry. I then have a 10px padding on the left and right of the bricks, making the bricks 220px wide.

Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/xECcm/

But if you notice, the bricks are too close together, so I added a margin-right to the .item bricks, and reduced the width of the bricks to make up for it. But then, the right most brick has a margin-right of 5px to it, so the bricks don't make up a full 960 pixel container, see :

http://jsfiddle.net/xECcm/2/

I tried adding a

```
.item:last-child{
    margin-right:0;
}
```

but that didn't work either, see: http://jsfiddle.net/xECcm/3/

So basically, I'm asking how do I make the last column of items have no margin-right, or a way to have the item/bricks fill up the entire 960 pixel container.

Thanks for all help. I know I probably phrased this question terrible, so if you have questions, just ask!

Comment: Like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/xECcm/4/) or [this](http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/xECcm/5/)? To be safe, I think your numbers need to change whatever you do, since `(960-30)/4 = 232.5` (not an integer). If this is what you're after, let me know and I'll write an answer.

Comment: @thirtydot, thats exactly what I need. Is this cross-browser though?

Comment: Sure, though it does need a small tweak to work in for example Firefox. I'll write an answer.

Comment: @thirtydot, Ok that'd be great. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The core idea to make this work is to use the [`gutter` option](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#gutter) in jQuery Masonry.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/xECcm/6/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $container = $('#container');
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: '.item',
        gutter: 12
    });
});
```

I used `box-sizing: border-box;` just to make the design easier to work with. If you didn't use it, you would have to adjust the `width` any time you change the horizontal padding:

```css
.container {
    width: 960px;
    background: #555;
}
.item {
    width: 231px;
    background: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px 15px 10px;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
         box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Lastly, to ensure that the boxes touch both edges of the container, you need to make sure that your numbers are "right".